# Authenticate through AD/LDAP

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap3

I don't know much about AD and LDAP, but trying to implement the most trivial LDAP/AD login function in Python. Lo luck so far though I tested several different modules. The most promising one might be [ldap3](https://github.com/cannatag/ldap3):

```
>>> import ldap3
>>> server = ldap3.Server('myserver')
>>> connection = ldap3.Connection(server)
>>> connection.bind()
True
>>> connection.search(search_base='DC=mydomain,DC=com', search_filter='(&(objectClass=person)(userPrincipalName=firstname.lastname@mydomain.com))', search_scope='LEVEL', attributes=ldap3.ALL_ATTRIBUTES)
True
>>> connection.response[0]
{'uri': ['ldap://ForestDnsZones.mydomain.com/DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=mydomain,DC=com??base'], 'type': 'searchResRef'}
>>> connection.result
{'result': 0, 'description': 'success', 'dn': '', 'message': '', 'referrals': None, 'type': 'searchResDone'}
```

Could you give me some pointers if this is on the right path or not?

The setup seems good enough for the basics, as I'm able to extract some type of metadata from it:

```
>>> server._get_dsa_info(connection)
>>> server._dsa_info
DSA info (from DSE):
  Supported LDAP versions: 3, 2
  Naming contexts:
    DC=mydomain,DC=com
    CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=com
    CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=com
    DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=mydomain,DC=com
    DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=mydomain,DC=com

  Supported controls:
    1.2.840.113556.1.4.1338 - Verify name - Control - MICROSOFT
    1.2.840.113556.1.4.1339 - Domain scope - Control - MICROSOFT
    1.2.840.113556.1.4.1340 - Search options - Control - MICROSOFT
    ...
```

I've also tried [flask-ldap3-login](https://github.com/nickw444/flask-ldap3-login), but is starting to suspect that our AD is not configured according to standard, as I'm getting:

```
...
>>> response = ldap_manager.authenticate('me', 'my_pass')
LDAPNoSuchObjectResult - 32 - noSuchObject - CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=com - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-0315270B, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
        'CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=com'
  - searchResDone - None
```

Please don't hesitate to ask for additional information, and I'll try to figure it out as best I can. For instance, my own user is located in:

```
CN=Lastname Firstname,OU=Consultants,OU=Users,OU=SE,OU=MYDOMAIN,DC=mydomain,DC=com
```

Some values are:

```
objectClass = top;person;organizationalPerson;user
name = Lastname Firstname
userPrincipalName = Firstname.Lastname@mydomain.com
```

Also, from `CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=com` there is only one subschema, which is `CN=Aggregate,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=com` and it looks empty. For some reason I believe this is what flask-ldap3-login tries to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem using the `ldap3.Connection` was that I didn't use a login when binding. This seems to be a way forward:

```
import ldap3
user = 'me@mycompany.com'
password = 'mypassword'
server = ldap3.Server('myserver')
connection = ldap3.Connection(server, user=user, password=password)
connection.bind()
connection.search(search_base='DC=mycompany,DC=com', search_filter='(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName='+user+'))', search_scope='SUBTREE', attributes='*')
```

And if you like to print some data:

```
attrs = connection.response[0]['attributes']
print(attrs['displayName'])
for memb in attrs['memberOf']:
    print(memb.partition('=')[2].partition(',')[0])
```